# $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^m y^n}{x^2 + y^2}$ exists iff $m+ n > 2$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I would like to prove, given $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^ny^m}{x^2 + y^2} \iff m+n>2.$$

(My gut tells me this should hold for $m,n \in \mathbb{R}^{>0}$ as well.) The ($\Rightarrow$) direction is pretty easy to show by contrapositive by familiar limit tricks. The ($\Leftarrow$) direction is giving me more trouble.

So far my strategy has been to use the arithmetic mean:

$$\left| \frac {x^n y^m} {x^2 + y^2}  \right| \leq \frac {x ^ {2n} + y ^ {2m}} {2 ( x^2 + y^2 ) } \leq \frac {x^ {2 (n-1)}} {2} + \frac { y^ {2 (m-1)} } {2},$$

but that's not helping if $m=1$, say.

Any ideas?

Apologies if this is a repeat...I couldn't find this on the site.

Comment: Try polar coordinates.

Comment: Indeed, you should prove the general result that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^\alpha y^\beta}{|x|^\gamma+|y|^\delta}$$ exists iff $\alpha/\gamma+\beta/\delta>1$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Does this more general result require $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta >0 $? Or just $\gamma, \delta > 0?$ Or none of the above?

Comment: Oops. Yes, sorry. I meant $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta>0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Any hints for beginning this proof?

Comment: Think along the lines of modified polar coordinates :)

Comment: @TedShifrin It seems we need absolute values in the top as well, otherwise we end up with complex values for fractional powers, right?

Comment: Yeah. Good. You nailed me :) I was trying to save keystrokes typing on my iPad. Maybe when you get it figured out, you can post the corrected general problem and answer :)

Comment: @TedShifrin I think I got the $(\Leftarrow)$ direction. Surprisingly, it's the $(\Rightarrow)$ direction that's giving me more trouble, showing divergence if $\alpha/\gamma + \beta / \delta \leq 1$. I'm having getting the denominator where I want it. Just factoring out $r^{\gamma}$ (assuming $\gamma < \delta$) doesn't seem to work. Got a hint for this way?

Comment: Did you try my suggestion of fudging polar coordinates to make things look as symmetric as possible?

Comment: Yes, for the $(\Rightarrow)$ direction I came up with $(r^{\alpha + \beta}(*))/(r^{\gamma}(1(*) + r^{\delta - \gamma})(*))$, where $(*)$ is some bounded trig stuff, and WLOG assume that $\gamma < \delta$, then $(\alpha + \beta)/\gamma >1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $m+n>2$, you can divide into two cases, by observing that you can't have $m<2$ and $n<2$.

First case: $m\ge2$.
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^ny^m}{x^2 + y^2}
=
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{y^2}{x^2 + y^2}x^ny^{m-2}
$$
where $n\ge1$ or $m-2\ge1$. The fraction is bounded, while the other factor tends to zero.

Similarly for $n\ge2$.